# fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") filenotfounderror: [errno 2] no such file or directory:

Tags: python, r, image, keras

I want to load a whole folder of images together. I am working in R using Keras with python interface. I have set the path of the folder, then used the lapply function to load the images in the folder, one by one.

```
> files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/acer/Desktop/Triparna/traitestimage/Test/Bone/", pattern=".png",all.files=T, full.names=F, no.. = T)
 > list_of_images = lapply(files, image_load)
```

The error :

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bone58.png'

Detailed traceback: 
File "C:\Users\acer\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site- 
packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 387, in load_img
img = pil_image.open(path)
File "C:\Users\acer\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site- 
packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2548, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
```

Can you please help me. I understand the python interface is unable to identify the path. But how do I do that?

Comment: You might want to run procmon with a filter to the filename, after this you know where the program looks for the files

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to path type; because it is not in path type when you're trying to access it.

Like if your path is:- `"my_path/this_way"`
Then:-

```py
import os
path1 = os.path.normpath("my_path/this_way")
```

Now use `path1`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but had similar issue with `keras::image_array_save`

My workaround was using `writeImage` from package OpenImageR. Works very well.

You could use `OpenImageR::readImage` instead of `image_load`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using vs code on my MacBook, I was working with image files in multiple subfolders. So what I did was place the folder I am working with in the Users root folder of my mac where the program and the image resources were residing and run it from there and it worked. It turned out vs code was having problems finding the files when they were placed deep in multiple subfolders.[FileNotFoundError solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvxf1.png)